# Breaking out of a procedure in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am trying to figure out a way to break out of a procedure if some external event occurs.  Let's say I have a procedure like this:

```
procedure p_RECEIVE_DATA (
o_data : out std_logic) is
begin

  wait until rising_edge(i2c_clock);
  o_data := i2c_data;
  wait until falling_edge(i2c_clock);

end procedure P_RECEIVE_DATA;
```

Now what I want is if an external signal, let's call it r_STOP gets asserted at any time, I want this procedure to exit immediately.  Is there a nice way to do this?  I was thinking that if this Verilog I could use fork/join_any to accomplish this, but there is no equivalent to fork and join in VHDL.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the code you have here might be just fine for a test or simulation. If this is what it's for, then great. However, keep in mind that code written as you have above is not synthesizable. You can compile and run it in a simulation setup, but you almost certainly won't be able to turn this into a hardware design for an FPGA, ASIC, or any other type of physical device. (In general, procedures can be used in synthesis only when they are called in a process and have no wait statements (or, less commonly, and only in some tools, when all of the wait statements are exactly the same).)

So to answer exactly what you've asked, the way to break out of a procedure is to call `return` when the condition you are interested in is met. For example if you wanted a global "r_stop" signal as you suggested make this procedure exit early no matter what whenever it changed to a '1', then you'd look for that explicitly:

```
procedure p_RECEIVE_DATA (
o_data : out std_logic) is
begin

  wait until rising_edge(i2c_clock) or r_stop = '1';
  if r_stop = '1' then return; end if;
  o_data := i2c_data;
  wait until falling_edge(i2c_clock) or r_stop = '1';
  if r_stop = '1' then return; end if;

end procedure P_RECEIVE_DATA;
```

Again, if this is not testbench code, but is meant to be synthesizable, you need to take a different approach and model your logic as an explicit finite state machine.

Comment: I'd use `r_stop = '1'` in the `wait`, otherwise you'll be sensitive to falling edges of `r_stop`.

Comment: @BenVoigt The original code presumes that this procedure would only be called when r_stop was not already '1', and I hate a polish a ... non-precious stone ... but I'll make an edit. =)

Comment: This works, thanks. I guess I'll just always need to check for the stop condition to break out of the procedure. Oh and yes this is 100% simulation only :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a nice solution to this in VHDL.  It's a bit like making [an inferred state machine](http://parallelpoints.com/inferred-state-machines-in-vhdl-vs-2-process-machines-of-all-things/) with a reset signal, which is also not pleasant.

You can do:

```
 wait until rising_edge(clk); exit when reset = 1;
```

within a loop.

I guess you could do:

```
 wait until rising_edge(clk); if stop = '1' then return; end if;
```

but again, not pleasant!

Answer (score 0):

Here my 2 cents.

You can do this in your main thread/process by calling trigger control signals for those other threads/processes.

Depending on the state of those control signals you can wait for any thread(join_any), all threads(join) or just do not wait (join_none).

Driving signals from multiple processes **is a bad idea** unless you really know what you're doing (**multiple driver problem**). *Therefore the activation and deactivation signal for each thread should be different since they are controlled from different processes/drivers.* That is the reason why i have written 2 control signals 1.started and 2.finished for each thread.
It is very important that a signal/interface is only written in one process in your code.

The code use **waits** so the same problems stated by ***wjl*** are applicable for synthesis.

If you want it **synthetizable** then put **thread_0_active** in the sensitivity list and do *if rising_edge(thread_0_active) then* inside the process. This will encapsulate the code and will be executed only in case of the rising condition. Of course the code inside this process should be synthetizable and contain no **waits**.

A state machine can only run and be in one state at a time.
I think you are interested on a direct equivalente to the systemverilog fork behavior. I have tried to make the example as close as possible.

The code below:

```
signal thread_0_started     : std_logic:='0';
signal thread_0_finished     : std_logic:='0';
signal thread_1_started     : std_logic:='0';
signal thread_1_finished     : std_logic:='0';
--......
p_main_father : process
   variable father_v : std_logic_vector( 32-1 downto 0 );   

begin
  --Do other things in your main thread using variables
  --
  --Now fork a thread activating it.
  thread_0_started <= '1';
  thread_1_started <= '1';
  --signals are activated and now we need to wait when they are finished
  --here both threads are started at the same time concurrently.
  ----------------------
  --a fork .. join_any would be to do an "or" until the logic
  wait until (thread_0_finished = '1') or (thread_1_finished = '1');
  -------------------
  --a fork .. join would be to do an "and" with the logic
  --wait until (thread_0_finished = '0') and(thread_1_finished = '0');
  --a fork .. join_none would be to just NOT do "wait until" and ignore that the threads were activated!!!     
  thread_0_started <= '0';--restore started state in case this main thread want to start them again.
  thread_1_started <= '0';

end process;

child_thread_0 : process
   variable prdata_v : std_logic_vector( 32-1 downto 0 );      
begin
   if thread_0_started = '0' then
      thread_0_finished <= '0';--important disable finished if not started
   end if;
   wait until rising_edge(thread_0_started);--trigger event
   --Do your things inside de thread_0 that consume time. e.g. calling other process
   thread_0_finished <= '1';
end process;

child_thread_1 : process
   variable prdata_v : std_logic_vector( 32-1 downto 0 ); 
begin
   if thread_1_started = '0' then
      thread_1_finished <= '0';--important disable finished if not started
   end if;
   wait until rising_edge(thread_1_started);
   --Do your things inside de thread_1 that consume time. e.g. calling other process
   thread_1_finished <= '1';
end process;
```